# How to fix ReportViewer showing the same report to multiple users in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

I've written a system using ASP.NET MVC that generates various financial reports. Each report is in it's own controller, each controller has its own "Report" Action. The Action Renders a partial view with the report in the ViewBag which it passes to javascript on the front end and puts the rendered element in a JQueryUI dialog.

A user may run a Balance Sheet report then another user may run an Income Statement report, after the first user runs the Balance Sheet Report and instead of seeing the Income Statement, the second user sees the Balance Sheet.

This is the code that returns the report as a JSON object

```
 //Initialize report and add datasources etc.
 reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
 ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;

 return Json(JsonResponse.Success(RenderRazorViewToString("PrintVoucher", null)));
```

Here is the Partial View

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc;


<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
</div>
```

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was this ever resolved? We're experiencing the same thing and keep hitting road blocks.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same issue and it seems to be related to a concurrency bug in the ReportViewerForMvc. Stumbled on this old github link which had the information and proposed fix. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/nrifath2009/ReportViewerForMvc/pull/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was the issue. The static classes were using the wrong reportviewer. We opted to use a strongly typed model instead of the ViewBag but the unique Guid ID flow is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your partial view a strongly typed view for "**reportViewer**" using it in the @Html.ReportViewer() and not the view bag.

After that go to the code that returns that partial view and on return set that as
**return Json(JsonResponse.Success(RenderRazorViewToString("PrintVoucher", reportViewer)));**

Comment: We are facing similar issue currently. It becomes a security breach as concurrent users get to see the report meant for other users. We have tried this solution but it has not worked.

Comment: This didn't solve our issue either. We're using a strongly typed model, not the ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your Action have no `OutputCache` attribute to make
   sure the server always calculate new report for each request or Set
   `VaryByParam` on attribute constructor
2. Use strongly type model instead of `ViewBag`
3. Initialize new object of the `ReportViewer` on each call instead of using a single static object.
4. Use `PartialView` on Controller action and pass the report object to the PartialView, Razor engine will process the Partial View with the model and generate an HTML markup as a return for the json call.

Here a working Sample of the controller and the View (I've used Bootbox instead of JqueryUI)

## Controller :

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult Report(/*Pass Optional Parameters If Required*/)
{
    var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    //reportViewerInitialization
    return PartialView("PrintVoucher", reportViewer);
}
```

## JavaScript Method for loading Report View

```
function showReport(reportControllerName)
{
    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
        message: '<p><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Loading...</p>'
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/'+ reportControllerName +'/Report/',
        data: {/*DataPassed To The Report Action*/},
        success: function (data) {
            //data Field will contain an Html markup resulted from razor engine process for PrintVoucher PartialView
            dialog.find('.bootbox-body').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

## PrintVoucher.cshtml

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc;
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            @Html.ReportViewer(Model as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```